# How can I restart a specificed interface instead of restart all interface?

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I have a server which OS is Ubuntu 18.04.03 configured four IP addresses on four different interfaces. Now there is a interface I need to restart, and I can not interfere with other three interfaces. So I think I can't using `sudo netplan apply`. Is there any way to restart specificed interface?
Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `sudo netplan apply` should not cause interfaces to be brought down, if there are no changes to the configuration for those interfaces.  So this should be safe to run.  If you find that this command restarts interfaces whose configuration has not changed, that's a bug and should be reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan.

Comment: Actually I found `sudo netplan apply` won't restart the interface which configuration is changed. For example my network wire is connected at `eth0` and I configured IP address on `eth1`. And I found it and I changed configure from `eth1` to `eth0` and execute `sudo netpl apply` then both `eth0` and `eth1` are configured same IP.

Comment: The issue you're running into is that if you completely /remove/ an interface from your netplan config, it is subsequently treated as unmanaged by netplan and therefore the removal of the interface is not propagated to the backend.  (Netplan itself is stateless - once you have edited its config files, it doesn't know what was there before, so can't distinguish between an interface you've dropped, and an interface that the user is managing natively through networkd.)  So if you want to move the configuration off of eth1, you need to do this manually with e.g. `ip link set eth1 down `.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactlly what I want.

Answer (score -1):

You can down and up the connection for particular interface with root permissions.

```
ifdown <interface_name>
ifup <interface_name>
```

Then reboot the system.

Comment: Reboot system is worse than execute `sudo netplan apply` in this situation. `ifup` and `ifdown` has been removed by default. Although these command can be installed by apt, this server can't access to Internet and I don't have local apt repo.

Comment: ifdown/ifup commands also are not present by default on Ubuntu 18.04, and only affect interfaces managed by ifupdown, not those managed through netplan.